# Somewhat new to programming - uploading a lot of programming related files to iCloud

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, icloud

I have been programming almost daily since earlier this year, and I have noticed a large amount of files being downloaded and uploaded in my gui. I believe that it is related to all of my code work being stored in my Documents, which are connected to my iCloud. Though, it never really seems to make substantial progress. I have been working and installing dependencies, create-react-apps and such.

How can I fix this before it becomes too much and avoid it in the future?

[my current gui showing files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1Jmg.png)

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the folder where your code and dependencies are, you can just create an empty file named `.nosync`. This will flag your iCloud to **don't** sync this folder with your online storage.

Comment: Cool, thank you. I will do that, but that would only really apply to code to be written, yeah? Unless I went through every other file I've created..

Comment: It applies to the folder. If you add this file, this folder will be ignored from now on. You can then delete it from the cloud, and it won't show up there anymore